# Printing a Square Matrix and Transposing it with Java

Tags: java, matrix, transpose, square

I need to write a program that will take a number n from the user and create an nxn matrix that counts up, then I need to transpose it. I've tried multiple methods of coding, but nothing displays correctly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SquareMatrix {
  public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Variables
    int size;
    int value;

    //Scanner
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Prompt
    System.out.println("Enter the size of the Square Matrix: ");
    size = input.nextInt();


    for(int i=1; i<=size; i++) {
        System.out.println();

        for(int j=0; j<size; j++) {

            value = i+j;
            System.out.print(value);

        }
     }

  }

}
```

The result I'm currently getting is:

```
Enter the size of the Square Matrix: 
3

123
234
345
```

I need it to look more like this:

```
Enter the Size of the Square Matrix:
3
Square Matrix:
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 
Transpose:
1 4 7 
2 5 8 
3 6 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nxn matrix counting up is

```
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        System.out.println();

        for(int j=1; j<=size; j++) {

            value = j + i*size;
            System.out.print(value);

        }
     }
```

The transponse is

```
  for(int i=1; i<=size; i++) {
        System.out.println();

        for(int j=0; j<size; j++) {

            value = j*size + i;
            System.out.print(value);

        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a code that does exactly what you need. It may seem overcomplicated but i think it grasp the idea that you would do with pencil and paper. You need to put the scanning user input part in though.

```
int n=10;
int[][] matrix =new int[n][n]; // a 2D array as one would imagine a matrix
int num=0;
int temp=0;// used in transposing


//initializing the arrays of the second dimension
for (int init=0;init<n;init++){ 
    matrix[init]=new int[n];
}

System.out.println("filling and printing matrix");
for (int fill_row=0;fill_row<n;fill_row++){
    for(int columns=0;columns<n;columns++){
        matrix[fill_row][columns]=++num;
        if(columns==n-1){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrix[fill_row]));
        }
    }
}


System.out.println("Transposed matrix");
for (int transp_row=0;transp_row<n;transp_row++){
        for(int columns=transp_row;columns<n;columns++){
            //store actual value to temp, 
            temp=matrix[transp_row][columns];
            //by switching the order of the indicies assign new value to current position
            matrix[transp_row][columns]=matrix[columns][transp_row];
            //assgin temp value to what we used as replacement
            matrix[columns][transp_row]=temp;
            if(columns==n-1){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrix[transp_row])); // print each rows of the array
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.